# How do I change the node.js version of the previous project?

Tags: node.js

[image]

Here is my node version on this computer
I'm going to download and run the previous project.
I installed [edge-js](https://github.com/agracio/edge-js) to use the c++ library, but the following message appears.

```
The edge module has not been pre-compiled for node.js version v8.2.1.

Uncaught Error: The edge module has not been pre-compiled for node.js version v8.2.1. You must build a custom version of edge.node. Please refer to https://github.com/agracio/edge-js for building instructions.

You must build a custom version of edge.node.
```

From this message, it seems that the current project version and edge-js library do not match.

I don't know how to change this. What I inferred may be wrong. If you happen to know how to deal with this case, please let me know.

Comment: Your title is asking about one of your proposed solution. Better ask about your real problem in the title.

Comment: have you tried `npm rebuild edge-js` or `yarn rebuild edge-js` ?

Comment: @DTan13 Yes I already to that.